# Creating a set of 3 buttons with different images on each

Tags: arrays, swift, button, uibutton

I'm trying to create a set of 3 buttons, each having a different image on them. I want them to be aligned horizontally, and for only one to be selected at a time (the first button in the array by default, and when you click another button, it deselects the previous selection). I'm a total n00b and I'm trying to depart a bit from a tutorial I did, which may explain why this is set up as an array of buttons rather than creating each one individually. My code is giving me an "expected ',' separator" error on each of the "for (index: ) lines. Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated, or please let me know if I should be going in a different direction to accomplish this. Thanks!
`

```
import UIKit
class RatingControl: UIView {

    var rating = 0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
        }
    var ratingButtons = [UIButton]()
    let spacing = 48
    let buttonCount = 3

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let lowUrgencyButtonSelected = UIImage(named: "LowUrgencyButtonSelected")
        let lowUrgencyButton = UIImage(named: "LowUrgencyButton")
        let mediumUrgencyButtonSelected = UIImage(named: "MediumUrgencyButtonSelected")
        let mediumUrgencyButton = UIImage(named: "MediumUrgencyButton")
        let highUrgencyButtonSelected = UIImage(named: "HighUrgencyButtonSelected")
        let highUrgencyButton = UIImage(named: "HighUrgencyButton")

        for (index: 0) in 0..<buttonCount {
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 49.5, y: 12.5, width: 60, height: 31))
            button.setImage(lowUrgencyButton, forState: .Normal)
            button.setImage(lowUrgencyButtonSelected, forState: .Selected)
            button.setImage(lowUrgencyButtonSelected, forState: [.Highlighted, .Selected])

            button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false

            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
            ratingButtons += [button]
            addSubview(button)
        }
        for (index: 1) in 0..<buttonCount {
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 49.5, y: 12.5, width: 60, height: 31))
            button.setImage(mediumUrgencyButton, forState: .Normal)
            button.setImage(mediumUrgencyButtonSelected, forState: .Selected)
            button.setImage(mediumUrgencyButtonSelected, forState: [.Highlighted, .Selected])

            button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false

            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
            ratingButtons += [button]
            addSubview(button)
        }
        for (index: 2) in 0..<buttonCount {
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 49.5, y: 12.5, width: 60, height: 31))
            button.setImage(highUrgencyButton, forState: .Normal)
            button.setImage(highUrgencyButtonSelected, forState: .Selected)
            button.setImage(highUrgencyButtonSelected, forState: [.Highlighted, .Selected])

            button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false

            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
            ratingButtons += [button]
            addSubview(button)
        }
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        var buttonFrame = CGRect(x: 49.5, y: 12.5, width: 60, height: 31)

        for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerate() {
            buttonFrame.origin.x = CGFloat(index * (60 + spacing))
            button.frame = buttonFrame
        }
        updateButtonSelectionStates()
    }

    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 60, height: 31)
    }

    func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
        rating = ratingButtons.indexOf(button)! + 1

        updateButtonSelectionStates()
    }

    func updateButtonSelectionStates() {
        for (index, button) in ratingButtons.enumerate() {
            button.selected = index < rating
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Please consider using a UISegmentedControl. It has most of what you need already done - a configurable amount of button that can only be selected one at a time, subclassed UIButton which means you can use images, etc. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Excellent, thank you dfd!